# jquery ui Autocomplete causing error with headers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm getting an error when trying to redirect. It only started after I installed a search box with autocomplete. When I pull the bit of code out, the page redirects properly again. I know it isn't my php.ini settings.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/content/67/6231767/html/nav.php:9) in
>   /home/content/67/6231767/html/admin/includes/functions2.php on line 7

Here is the code that is causing the problem. Thanks for your help!

```
$(function() { $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/includes/links.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function( xmlResponse ) {
            var data = $( "link", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                return {
                    value: $( "title", this ).text(),
                    id: $( "url", this ).text()
                };
            }).get();
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: function (request, response) {
                    var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term)
                        , startsWithMatcher = new RegExp("^" + term, "i")
                        , startsWith = $.grep(data, function(value) {
                            return startsWithMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
                        })
                        , containsMatcher = new RegExp(term, "i")
                        , contains = $.grep(data, function (value) {
                            return $.inArray(value, startsWith) < 0 &&
                                containsMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
                        });

                    response(startsWith.concat(contains));
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) { window.location.href = ui.item.id; }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the error you posted is a PHP error. there should be no errors in your javascript code if that is the only error you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not post your PHP code that is causing the error, this is the best band-aid solution I can provide.

In your functions2.php, put `ob_start();` on top. Here are some resources that will explain this:

http://brian.moonspot.net/php-ob-start-headers

http://php.net/ob_start

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your javascript but with your php output.  Something in your php script is attempting to write before you write your headers and send your info (probably a php error).  What is on lines 7 and 9 of your php script?